# Ticket to Ride trade original destination cards later in the game

Tags: ticket-to-ride

About your original destination cards in Ticket to Ride North America (the three you get at the beginning of the game):

Can you trade them later in the game? Our group is not sure.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot trade destination cards at all: neither the ones you receive at the start nor any you receive later.

You get three at the start and can choose to keep all three or just two (discarding the other one). [Rulebook](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_2015_en.pdf):

> Shuffle the Destination Ticket cards and deal 3 cards to each player. Each player
>   looks at their Destination Tickets and decides which ones they wish to keep. A player
>   must keep at least two, but may keep all three if he chooses. Any returned cards are
>   placed on the bottom of the Destination Ticket deck. This deck is then placed next to the
>   board. Players keep their Destination Tickets secret until the end of the game.

For destination cards drawn during the game as an action, you draw three and keep one or more, discarding the one(s) you don't keep.

Again rulebook:

> – The player draws 3 Destination Tickets from the top of the deck. He must keep at least one of them, but he may keep
>   two or all three if he chooses. Any returned cards are placed on the bottom of the deck.

There is no mechanism for trading them or discarding them later.